# Installing ruby on rails by using Dockerfile "Could not locate gemfile" during build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, dockerfile

I have a school task which needs me to do this:

> You are going to create your first Dockerfile to containerize Rails
>   applications. That’s a special configuration: this particular
>   Dockerfile will be generic, and called in another Dockerfile, that
>   will look something like this:

```
FROM ft-rails:on-build
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["rails", "s", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-p", "3000"]
```

> Your generic container should install, via a ruby container, all the
>   necessary dependencies and gems, then copy your rails application in
>   the /opt/app folder of your container. Docker has to install the
>   appropriate gems when it builds, but also launch the migrations and
>   the db population for your application. The child Dockerfile should
>   launch the rails server (see example below). If you don’t know what
>   commands to use, it’s high time to look at the Ruby on Rails
>   documentation.

Right now my Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM ruby

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install -y sqlite3 build-essential nodejs libpq-dev
RUN gem update && gem install rails && gem install bundler
RUN mkdir /opt/app

ONBUILD WORKDIR /opt/app/
ONBUILD ADD . /opt/app

ONBUILD EXPOSE 3000
ONBUILD RUN bundle install
ONBUILD RUN rake db:setup
ONBUILD RUN rake db:seed
```

When I build this Dockerfile it works fine.
When I go back to my generic dockerfile given in the assignment and try to build this one, I get the error:

```
Could not locate Gemfile
The command '/bin/sh -c bundle install' returned a non-zero code: 10
```

I am no expert in ruby on rails and have just started using it for this assignment. I have no idea what I am doing wrong or how to fix this and have looked online for an answer without success...
Any help is super welcome!

Comment: What is the structure of /opt/app - is there a `Gemfile` in the root directory of /opt/app ? Bundler depends on this and will fail if it is not present as it defines the dependencies that are to be installed by `bundle install`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you build it, make sure you are in your Rails project root folder. You should already have run `rails new your-project-name` in this folder to generate this.

The command `ONBUILD ADD . /opt/app` will copy the current folder recursively into the Docker image, so it must already contain Gemfile and all other parts of the Rails project.

Comment: I thought the objective would be to run an existing Rails app?

Comment: To be honest, it's unclear. Maybe we should ask the OP to clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Bundler (which installs gems - ruby libraries) uses a file that is called Gemfile. It creates a Gemfile.lock file that stores versions of each gem from a Gemfile and it's dependencies.

What you are missing is that Gemfile file in your project's folder.

You need to add that Gemfile.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '~>5'
```

And a Gemfile.lock

```
touch Gemfile.lock
```

I know it's not an exact answer to your question but read the docs here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/

Comment: As on January 14th, 2024 the link https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/ throws a 404